# Unable to display images after Drupal Update

Tags: updating, media

I recently updated my site to Drupal 7.34 using these instructions -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uDTyzE47pQ

After update, I am not able to see the images in the site. All I see is the placeholder for image, but not the image itself. I checked and its not a path issue.

This is how it looked before -
[image]

And this is how it looks after -
[image]

Also notice that the theme has changed. I was using bartik before. Can somebody tell me if I did anything wrong or how to get the images to display? Could this be an issue with image styles?

Comment: First off, update to 7.35! right click on the image, what is its link?

Comment: I am about to update to 7.35 but I dont want to face a similar issue there. This is the link of the image -drupal/sites/default/files/2_201.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, I finally found a solution as per [SA-CORE-2013-003 - Drupal core - Multiple vulnerabilities](https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2013-11-20/sa-core-2013-003-drupal-core).

I changed the content of the .htaccess file in the sites/default/files folder to this.

```php
#SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
#Options None

Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006

<Files *>
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

I was able to see the images again.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you didn't correctly copy sites/all and sites/default/ over during the update or the permissions on the files in those directories aren't correct so Drupal can only "see" core modules and themes.  The data in the database is still working, but any field, content type, or url that requires a module from sites/all probably doesn't work either.

Comment: I checked, the permission are the same for the folders.